# how can we keep two cells of a table together without leaving some part of any page blank

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I want to keep two cells of a table keep together. So as per below code i gave cell as keep together. 
I gave here example for two inner tables actually there are more.
So if both heading and content cell are not able to fit in the page then it starts from next page. But requirement is part of page  should not be blank and heading and content should always be together. If content size is more then only content may split.

```
Table outerTable =new Table(1);
Table innerTable1 =new Table(1);
String content="";/*Large content from a text file*/
Cell cell1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Heading1"));
Cell cell2 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(content));
innerTable1.add(cell1);
innerTable1.add(cell2);
Cell cell =new Cell().add(innerTable1).setKeepTogether(true);
outerTable.add(cell);
Table innerTable2 =new Table(1);
cell1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Heading2"));
cell2 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(content));
innerTable2.add(cell1);
innerTable2.add(cell2);
cell =new Cell().add(innerTable2).setKeepTogether(true);
outerTable.add(cell);
```